# Can't get my uitabbar to appear when setting it up programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

So I have been looking all over the place for examples for how to create a uitabbar prpgrammatically. I tried my best to take what I need from every example and to put together how I want my app to look like: a welcome screen following a 2-tab tabbar.

I have a view controller for the welcome screen with a UIButton to move on:

```
-(IBAction)aMethod:(id)sender {

    MyTabProjectViewController *controller = [[MyTabProjectViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];
    }

Then in my MyTabProjectViewController.m I do this:


    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //Setting up the view
    UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.view = contentView;    

    //Declaring all view controllers
    FirstView *first = [[FirstView alloc] init];
    SecondView *second = [[SecondView alloc] init];

    //Set titles for the view controllers
    first.title = @"First";
    second.title = @"Second";


    UITabBarController *tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    tabBarController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);


    UINavigationController *nvc1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:first];
    UINavigationController *nvc2 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:second];

    nvc1.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
    nvc2.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;


    NSArray *controllers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:nvc1, nvc2, nil];

    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;

    [self.view addSubview:tabBarController.view];    
    }
```

From some reason nothing works. When I click on the button to go to MyTabProjectViewController I see a blank page.

Comment: i see a leak in your method, try to release the controller [controller release]; after presentModal...

Comment: using garbage collection...no leaks :) Thanks!

Comment: You have to release it, and i think you have to call release on contentView,first,second,tabBarController,nvc1,nvc2, and controllers; if you are instantiate a non-ivar why you don't release it after you have used it?

Comment: @TommyG iPhone doesn't have GC on device, unless you are using ARC?

Comment: @MCannon What is ARC stands for?

Comment: @Rahul Vyas look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6576674/does-ios-5-have-garbage-collection

Comment: @Mat thanks for the information I was not aware of this. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You instantiating a new instance of the UITabBarController and setting the ViewControllers list to another instance, just replace the line:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```

with the line:

```
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
```