# Zeroing Weak References in ARC

Tags: objective-c, clang, automatic-ref-counting

If my reading of Mike Ash's ["Zeroing Weak References" writeup](http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html) is correct, weak references are like `assign` references without ARC. However, if the referenced object is deallocated, instead of getting a "dangling pointer" (meaning a pointer that points to a deallocated object), the pointer gets set to `nil`.

Is this right, and **does this happen with any property marked `weak` or `assign` (when ARC is active)?**

If this is correct, this would eliminate a lot of SIGABRTs.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It's mostly right, but `assign` properties are still treated the same as they ever were, only `weak` ones are zeroing. Another caveat is that zeroing weak references are only available in Mac OS X ≥ 10.7 and iOS ≥ 5. While the rest of ARC was backported to 10.6 and iOS 4, weak references cannot be used at all on these OS's.

Comment: Thanks for that @cobbal. At least in XCode 4.2 beta, you CANNOT use `weak` in a property declaration if your deployment target is < iOS 5: you must use `assign`. Message is `error: the current deployment target does not support automated __weak references`

Comment: Thank you @Yar, I was getting that error and did not know where it came from!

Comment: Doesn't iOS 4 support __unsafe_unretained as a substitute for __weak?

Comment: @MarkAdams it does, but as the name implies they are unsafe. When the object a weak references points to is destroyed, the weak reference goes to nil. With unsafe_unretained references, however, the reference points to the same (now deallocated) chunk of memory, and any messages sent to it will likely result in a segfault.

Comment: Further note: Mac OS X 10.6 support is limited to 64-bit apps; 32-bit code uses the legacy runtime and can’t use ARC at all.

Comment: Note: You can now use __weak with iOS4 and 10.6 by using https://github.com/plausiblelabs/PLWeakCompatibility

Comment: Does this also go for `__weak` ivars or just properties?

Comment: @chaiguy yep, a `weak` property just means it uses a `__weak` ivar, so they'll be exactly the same.