# ARC and custom deallocs

Tags: objective-c

Out of curiosity/excitement I have been reading whatever information I can find about ARC but I have one question I can't seem to find the answer to. Not sure if people can answer this due to NDAs or whatever, but I'll ask anyway. (There's plenty of information out there.......)

One thing ARC advertises is that you won't need to write dealloc methods anymore. Cool. But is this really true?

If I have a NSNetService or something, normally in my dealloc I would write

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [netService_ setDelegate:nil];
    [netService_ stop];
    [netService_ release];

    [super dealloc];
}
```

Does ARC take care of that now? Or is not smart enough to know about stuff like that? If it isn't smart enough to know about that stuff (meaning I would still have to write custom deallocs in certain cases) would I have to release all ivars? Or just ones that wouldn't be simple releases?

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [netService_ setDelegate:nil]; // if these 3 lines are necessary...
    [netService_ stop];
    [netService_ release];

    [myString_ release]; // would this one still be? or would ARC know to automagically add this
    [super dealloc]; // seems this is forbidden in ARC
}
```

I guess my question really boils down to this: ARC says you won't have to write deallocs anymore in most cases; so when are the cases you do have to?

Comment: Whenever you do write your own dealloc, don't forget to call [super dealloc] (as you have in your sample code)

Comment: Thanks. I'll edit. I left it out because I believe it's an error to call that when ARC is enabled.

Comment: @Danra, you don't call `[super dealloc]` under ARC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I understand it, you should think of ARC as just the static-analyzer built into the compiler, synthesizing retain and release calls where required (Which is also the reason why ARC code will be backwards-compliant with devices running iOS4).

So there is no way `netService_` in your sample will be stopped automatically. You will need to write your own dealloc in this case.

The delegate issue is interesting, in iOS5 lingo it will be a weak property so it might be set to nil on dealloc... Not sure but it's interesting!

Another case you will have to take of yourself is you have handle objects which aren't objective-c objects, for example for Core Foundation objects you will need to write `CFRetain`s and `CFRelease`s yourself.

Comment: Ahh yes, I remember reading about those zeroing weak properties now... you're right that should theoretically handle itself. I guess you can't rely on every class having there delegate as a weak property though?

Comment: Every well written class should have its delegate as a weak/assign property. See also this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246513/zeroing-weak-references-in-arc

Answer (score 2):

I think that if there is anything you need to do to cleanup an object, *other* than releasing it, is fair game for a custom dealloc method.

So in your own example with `netService_`, the calls to `setDelegate:` and `stop` would be reasonable to call, but there'd be no need to call `release` because ARC takes care of that.

Comment: That's great if that's how it truly is. Seems reasonable.

Comment: The `setDelegate:` call should be unnecessary, assuming that it's properly set up as a zeroing weak reference. @user988375

Comment: @JoshCaswell what if the delegate (or another object) were a `strong` reference? Then you'd need to set it to `nil` in the dealloc?

Comment: @Yar: Yes, if the object of which this being-deallocated object is the delegate was expected to live on.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Just ran a small test, apparently ARC will set strong properties to nil when an object is dealloc'ed. Interesting. Wrote answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that ARC wouldn't know about your `[netService_ stop];` line. You'd have to include that yourself, since it's non-standard and does not have to do with `retain`/`release`.

Right after your `dealloc` is run, ARC will release all `strong` and `weak` properties (and `__strong` and `__weak` iVars).

Here's some test code, just to see what happens:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) TestClass *anotherTestObject;

@end


@implementation TestClass
@synthesize anotherTestObject;

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"I am deallocing %d", self.hash);
}

@end
```

And my test:

```
TestClass *thing1 = [[TestClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"thing 1 %d", thing1.hash);

thing1.anotherTestObject = [[TestClass alloc] init];
NSLog(@"thing 2 %d", thing1.anotherTestObject.hash);
```

This will print out something like this

```
thing 1 1450176
thing 2 1459984
I am deallocing 1450176
I am deallocing 1459984
```

Since only one of the objects is getting autoreleased (`thing1`) at the end of the test code, you can immediately tell that `thing2` is getting released by someone else (since it's in a `strong` property). However, if you overwrite `setAnotherTestObject` you find that ARC is **not** setting it to `nil` but rather just releasing it directly. You cannot override `release` in ARC, otherwise I could demonstrate this too ;)

If I adjust the code and use `weak` instead of `strong`, the same behavior persists, but the output is different since the test case isn't holding onto the weak reference whatsoever.