# Is there any statistics on what propotion of iOS-device is running iOS5?

Tags: ios5, statistics

Is there any statistics on what propotion of iOS-device is running iOS5?

I'm gonna developing a iOS App and I need to know that in order to decide do I support iOS4.
(I want to use Storyboard and ARC)

Comment: ARC is supported in iOS4. If you have to support storyboards though, then you're right in that you won't be able to support iOS4.

Comment: weak reference is not supported in iOS4.

Comment: Zeroing weak references aren't, but an `__unsafe_unretained` variable acts like a weak reference. See [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7246513/zeroing-weak-references-in-arc) for more info.

Comment: It doesn't act anything like a zeroing-weak reference, except in that it won't leak. Aside from that, they're absolutely nothing alike.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [these statistics](http://www.marco.org/2011/11/30/more-ios-device-and-os-version-stats-from-instapaper):

- iOS 5 is not much more than 50% (since that data is a few months old now)
- iOS 4 is the vast majority of remaining devices

So I wouldn't lock yourself into iOS5-only development at this time.