# Does arc works for ios4 as well?

Tags: ios

I am working in xcode4.2 and enabled ARC for my app, I want my app to support ios4 and ios5.
So,Does ios4 support ARC?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is ARC really supported in iOS 4? The iOS 4.2 SDK is missing ARC-related symbols at linking time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747783/is-arc-really-supported-in-ios-4-the-ios-4-2-sdk-is-missing-arc-related-symbols)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, iOS 4 and greater used with Xcode 4.2 and greater supports ARC. (Weak references are not supported in Mac OS X v10.6 and iOS 4).

Answer (score 0):

ARC is supported on iOS 4.0 and above. You need to use the iOS 5.x SDK but can select iOS 4.3 for the Deployment Target. The one thing that is not supported in 4.x is automatic weak reference zeroing.

for more details refer this..

[Is ARC really supported in iOS 4? The iOS 4.2 SDK is missing ARC-related symbols at linking time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747783/is-arc-really-supported-in-ios-4-the-ios-4-2-sdk-is-missing-arc-related-symbols)