# Can't get my iPhone app to install on a 3G

Tags: iphone, xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I've been trying to get my app - built in Xcode 4.2 in Snow Leopard, using ARC, targeting iOS 4.0 and up - to install on a 3G, with no luck. I've tried every solution I can find (like this thorough one here: [Is it possible to target older iOS versions when using Xcode 4.2 and iOS 5 SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7760946/is-it-possible-to-target-older-ios-versions-when-using-xcode-4-2-and-ios-5-sdk)) and while I've been able to get the app to *run* on the phone via Xcode, when I share the app and try to install it through iTunes, I keep getting the same error telling me the app was not installed because it is not compatible with this iPhone. My client is using a 3G so this is a pretty big problem.

I've set the architectures / valid architectures to support armv6 as well as armv7 in my build settings and I've deleted the line in info.plist about the required device capabilities with armv7 (I also experimented with adding armv6 instead of deleting the line, which made no difference). I also added the -mno-thumb to Other C Flags in case that was the issue. Even though I know for a fact that it *works* on a 3G, iTunes refuses to install it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Have you tried setting your deployment target as 4.3?

Comment: I tried setting it to 4.2 with the same results. Any higher than that and the 3G wouldn't run it, I should think.

Comment: are you using any weak references?

Comment: No. And again, when I run the app on the phone in Xcode, it works fine - so I don't think the issue is with my code, I think there's some setting buried somewhere that's telling iTunes it won't run on armv6.

Comment: Are you coming across this issue after sharing the app with your client? Are you sure that your debug and adhoc settings for the app are the same?

Comment: Yes, this comes up when I share the app - I've been able to duplicate my client's problem by syncing the app in iTunes on my own 3G. All my build settings, in Project and Targets, include armv6 like they're supposed to. Is there any other setting that could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I'm just dumb - I skipped a step and wasn't actually re-archiving the app, I just kept sharing the same original archive over and over again. Re-archived and now it works fine.

Thanks for all your help, everybody! Next time I ask a question I'll try to rule out my own lack of attention first...:P

Answer (score 0):

Check the OS version for you iPhone 3G. if it is running less than 4.0 you might need to have older sdk. Besides I guess ARC is not supported in earlier versions of iOS.

Comment: It's running 4.2.1 (8C148). That's the last update compatible with the 3G, it seems.

Comment: iOS 4 supports ARC according to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7747783/is-arc-really-supported-in-ios-4-the-ios-4-2-sdk-is-missing-arc-related-symbols

Comment: @jaytr0n:Sorry,I meant earlier version of iOS less than 4.0